# PageMethods not working if the website is created as a Visual C# ASP.Net Web Application in VS2015

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pagemethods

I am a newbie in web developing with VS (Visual Studio). I have the following problem and would appreciate it very much if you could share your view on this.

**PROBLEM:**
PageMethods works OK if I create a new website in VS via [File] - [New Web Site] - [ASP.NET Empty Web Site] as per the files given below.
But if I create a new website in VS via [File] - [New Project] - [Visual C# ASP.NET Web Application] then PageMethods do NOT work as per the files given below. Moreover, I can not run any method created in aspx.cs files!

Obviously, I am missing a basic step/concept but I can not see it unfortunately!

**ASPX File:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test4.aspx.cs" Inherits="ETDBWebApplication1.Content.Test.Test4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm1" EnablePageMethods="true" />
        <div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function getValues() {
                    var text1 = $('#txt1').val();
                    PageMethods.GetValues(text1, getValues_Success, getValues_Fail);
                }
                function getValues_Success(msg){
                    $('#div1').html(msg);
                }
                function getValues_Fail(msg) {
                    alert(msg.get_message());
                }
            </script>
            <input type="text" id="txt1" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" onclick="getValues();" value="get values"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="div1"></div>
        </div>
    </form></body>
</html>
```

**ASPX.CS FILE (CODEBEHIND):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ETDBWebApplication1.Content.Test
{
    public partial class Test4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetValues(string value)
        {
            value = value + DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString();
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ETDBWebApplication1-20200211070838.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ETDBWebApplication1-20200211070838;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Many thanks in advance.
Cenk

Comment: Because you said this - `Moreover, I can not run any method created in aspx.cs files!` - just want to understand if you double checked the `Build Action` property value on your code-behind file, the value should be `Compile`

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. But, they seem to be OK as shown below:  Aspx file Properties-Build: Content   Aspx.cs file Properties-Build: Compile

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ScriptMethod` instead of `WebMethod` attribute on the method `GetValues` and if it still fails, decorate the aspx.cs class with `ScriptService` attribute.